# Extract a section of a string based on the value of another column in python

Tags: python, string, pandas

I want to extra the first portion of column (B) based on the value of another column (A) minus 1 to get an output. Eg, if column A is 4 than I want the first 3 characters of column B.

Any suggestions? Greatly appreciated!

```
+---+---------------+------+
| A |       B       | Out  |
+---+---------------+------+
| 4 |  CTAAT        |  CTA |
| 3 |  GKAEI        |  GK  |
+---+---------------+------+
```

ie first 3 letters of column B in row 1, the fist 2 letters of column B in row 2.

My current approach that isn't working:

`df['output']= df.B.str[0:(df[A]-1)]`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [pandas.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
df['output']=df.apply(lambda x: x['B'][:x['A']-1], axis=1)
print(df)

A      B         output
4      CTAAT     CTA
3      GKAEI     GK
```

Comment: This is giving me the error:TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method

Comment: Okay, I see what you are saying. I did not have the 'output' column created yet, but was relying on the column to be created with the line of code. Thanks! That did work for me.

Comment: Nevermind, I am still having issues with getting the error I listed above. It did give me the correct output once, but not it is giving me the error again. Any insights to why I wouldn't be able to reference the column? dtypes lists it as an int.

Comment: You are saying that you got the right output and also getting the error ? Could you explain what's the issue

Comment: Yes, sorry for the confusion. I am operating in Jupyter and launch the cell, which gave the error "TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an index method". I went back and added an empty 'output' column to the df prior to the pandas.apply function. Then, when I reran the cell with pandas.apply, it worked. But, the same error appears as before whenever I run the entire script from the beginning.